# How to play videos in android?

Tags: android, video, playback, android-videoview

How can I play videos in android application,
when the videos are placed in res/raw folder?

Comment: this question has been asked several times, before asking atleast you should search first !!

Answer (score 2):

Use  MediaPlayer and yes you will play from your res/raw folder

```
   MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
    mp.start();
```

[Audio and Video Playback](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/media/index.html)